# Why does my Dask job's performance get worse after five workers?

Tags: kubernetes, dask-distributed, dask-kubernetes

I am running Dask on an eight-node Kubernetes cluster with my manifest specifying one scheduler replica and eight worker replicas. My code is processing 80 files of about equal size, and I wanted to see how performance scales from one worker to eight. I'm doing something roughly like this:

```py
client: distributed.client.Client = get_client()
workers = client.scheduler_info()['workers']
worker_ips: List[str] = list(workers.keys())

my_files: List[str] = ["list", "of", "files", "to", "be", "processed", "..."]

# This dictionary maps a worker ip to a uniform subset of my_files
files_per_worker = {
    "worker_ip1" : ["list", "to", "..."],        # files for worker1 only
    "worker_ip2" : ["of", "be"],          # files for worker2 only
    "worker_ip3" : ["files", "processed"] # files for worker3 only
    }

# Send each worker a subset of the work
futures = [client.submit(do_work, subset_of_files, workers=[ip])
    for (ip, subset_of_files) in files_per_worker.items()]

# Get results from each node, blocking until completion, and reducing partial results into final version
result = finalize_partial_results([f.result() for f in futures])
```

The simplified summary of results is:

- One node is the slowest (not surprising)
- Five nodes is the fastest (taking about 25% as long as one node)
- Six nodes spikes (about 80% longer than five nodes, barely better than half the time for one node)
- Seven and more nodes are pretty flat - there's not much incremental performance gain. But also, it doesn't get back to the performance of five nodes.

I would have thought that eight - one worker per physical node - would be optimal, but this isn't the case. I even tested this with different input datasets of varying sizes; five nodes is always the best with a big jump at six nodes.

What might be causing this, and how can I avoid this performance degradation? As far as I can tell, each `worker_ip` represents a physical node, so work should be uniformly shared across the subset of workers selected.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I recently had a similar experience.

Comment: @MatthewBorish - No, I never found a resolution to this. I may revisit my analysis now that my code is in prod and I have optimized other aspects of it. If/when I do, I'll try to update this question with relevant info.